# NSTimer cancel my UIView.animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, swift

Every time NSTimer is called my animation is canceled

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)  

    self.mover()
}

/**
 Selector

 - parameter timer: NStimer
 */
func timer(timer:NSTimer!){
    self.lblTiempo.text = "Te haz movido"
}
```

How can I prevent NSTimer cancel my animations?

```
/**
 Mueve la imagen en la pantalla
 */
func mover(){


    let x = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32( 400 )))
    let y = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32( 400 )))

    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.juego!.velocidad,
        delay: 0.0,
        options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .AllowUserInteraction],
        animations: {
            self.imgBicho.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        },
        completion: { finished in
            self.mover()
    })
}
```

I am relatively new to the development of IOS, someone can help me with this, thanks.

Sure **paulvs**, Sorry it is a misspelling. The problem is with the NSTimer :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you posted will crash straight away with an exception like this

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TestTimer.ViewController timer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb501c3faa0'
```

because the `timer` function has one argument

```
func timer(timer:NSTimer!){
```

while your `NSTimer` initialisation code passes a selector with no arguments

```
_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

To fix this, change this line to

```
_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

notice the colon `:` near the end.

Comment: Sure paulvs, Sorry it is a misspelling. The problem is with the NSTimer :(

Comment: I literally copied your code into an empty project, wired the `UILabel` and `UIImageView` to `lblTiempo` and `imgBicho`, respectively. Then I replaced `self.juego!.velocidad` with `1`, and ran the project and got an image dancing around the screen. So what exactly is the problem you are getting? Does the image move at all?

Comment: When the view is updated with the timer, my image disappears and appears on the other hand, my animation not conclude. Excuse my English, I do not speak or write very well. If I remove the timer, the image moves fluidly, not disappear.

Comment: Your `NSTimer` has nothing to do with the image animations (it simply sets the label text to `Te haz movido`). You could remove all the `NSTimer` code and the image should still animate without any problem.

Comment: Yes, I hold the timer because I would like to implement a counter regressively (10, 9, 8, 7, etc.)

Comment: I suggest you try to find where exactly the bug is in your code by commenting out unrelated parts and compiling until you get your animations working. If you post more code I might be able to help you further, too.

Comment: Sure, thanks paulvs, y going to update my code, Thanks